# Check build parameters of libxml2.so at runtime

Tags: c, linux, gcc, libxml2, autoconf

I am writing a simple application that links to `libxml2` on the system. It works for almost all users, but one user reported this error when reading a particular xml file from the web:

```
Unsupported encoding ISO8859-1
```

This error typically indicates that libxml2 was built `--without-iconv`. Is there any way I can explicitly test if the libxml2 dynamic library on the system has iconv support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this:

1. Write a short, simple test program that uses the iconv feature of xml.  It should behave differently if it is not present.  This is what the GNU configure software does - it tests for features being present by exercising them.
2. This is a hack - find a common iconv symbol present in libxml with iconv but not if iconv is missing.  Use a utility like *nm* to list the symbols in the library file.

Or just avoid the issue by packaging a working libxml with your application.

Comment: I don't think back-end support for iconv will affect exported symbols.